# Difference between "Discriminant", "Discriminative" and "Discriminating"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

Let us assume I am writing some technical CS stuff, and I want to talk about "features" of something that discriminate something else.

Translating from my native language (French), I would use the word + adjective:

> Discriminant features

However, I have stumbled in reads upon the word "Discriminative" and "Discriminating".

According to Wiktionary, we have:

> Discriminant (Adj.): Serving to discriminate.
>
> Discriminative (Adj.): Which has the ability to discriminate between things; or which imparts such ability
>
> Discriminating (Adj.): Able to perceive fine distinctions between similar things; perceptive

So if I understand this correctly, Discriminating does not have the same meaning as the other two, i.e. discriminating is an adjective for someone/something that perceives the differences, instead of caracterizing them.

However it is not clear, with regards to the definition of Wiktionary, whether *Discriminative* and *Discriminant* are perfect synonyms, or if one is more used in some context than an other, or if they don't exactly mean the same thing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost right;

```
His comments about the attack discriminated against those people
```

or possibly

```
His comments about the attack were discriminating against those people who weren't involved.
```

Back to the question; discriminant and discriminative are pretty much obscure and obsolete. Discriminate is almost exclusively used in its verbal form.

Discriminant is a noun describing a property that discriminates.

```
The discriminant between red squirrels and grey is their colour
```

Discriminative is an adjective and applies to the object **but** is not the same as discriminating = prejudice.

```
He was discriminative, disliking red sweets and liking green ones
```

Answer (score 0):

Discriminating is used to describe something that a subject is doing. It is not an adverb because it does not describe a verb directly.

```
His comments about the attack was discriminating to those people who aren't involved.
```

As you can see in the example sentence. Discriminating was used to describe an action or something that he did. It was discriminating.

```
He is Discriminative when it comes to attacks. He always thinks it was everyone else's fault.
```

As you can see Discriminative is used to describe somone. He is Discriminative when it comes to attacks.